# Linq Join Two List , Group By Result And Select Distinct Value

Tags: c#, linq

I plan to join 2 list, and group by barcode and get the distinct value of reducedPrice and ItemPrice column. How should I achieve that in Linq?
(And I want intersect result. I don't want data from list2 such as Barcode 003,004,005)
This is what I've tried.

```
var sameJanWithDiffPriceList3 = (from item in list1                                                 
                                 join t in list2 on item.BarcodeNo equals t.BarcodeNo
                                 group item by item.BarcodeNo
                                 into grp
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     BarcodeNo = grp.Key,
                                     ReducedPrice = grp.Select(x => x.ReducedPrice).Distinct().Count(),
                                     ItemPrice = grp.Select(x => x.ItemPrice).Distinct().Count()
                                  }).ToList();
```

### List 1

| Barcode | reducedPrice | ItemPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | 100 | 120 |
| 000 | 320 | 420 |
| 001 | 200 | 360 |
| 001 | 400 | 860 |
| 002 | 120 | 160 |
| 099 | 120 | 160 |

### List 2

| Barcode | reducedPrice | ItemPrice | ItemCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | 100 | 120 | 00 |
| 001 | 200 | 360 | 01 |
| 002 | 120 | 160 | 02 |
| 003 | 120 | 160 | 02 |
| 004 | 120 | 160 | 02 |
| 005 | 120 | 160 | 02 |

### Result I Want

| Barcode | Count(DistinctReducedPrice) | Count(DistinctItemPrice) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | 2 | 2 |
| 001 | 3 | 3 |
| 002 | 1 | 1 |
| 099 | 1 | 1 |

### Result I Get

| Barcode | Count(DistinctReducedPrice) | Count(DistinctItemPrice) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | 2 | 2 |
| 001 | 2 | 2 |
| 002 | 1 | 1 |
| 099 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: @Arcord I edited the Question. Please check. Thank .

Comment: I don't know result of code what you've tried, but looks like you just need to use `Count` instead of `ToList`

Comment: @demo I edit the question with the result I get. Please check. Thank .

Comment: If you want the intersection why the result has "099", since list2 doesn't contain it? Also, why do you expect 3 for "001" since it only has 2 different values (200 and 400)?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var list2 = new List<(string Barcode,int reducedPrice, int ItemPrice,string ItemCode)>{
    ("000",100,120,"00"),
    ("001",200,360,"01"),
    ("002",120,160,"02"),
    ("003",120,160,"02"),
    ("004",120,160,"02"),
    ("005",120,160,"02")
};

var list1 = new List<(string Barcode,int reducedPrice, int ItemPrice)>{
    ("000",100,120),
    ("000",320,420),
    ("001",200,360),
    ("001",400,860),
    ("002",120,160),
    ("099",120,160)
};


var result = list1.Select(x=>new {x.Barcode,x.reducedPrice,x.ItemPrice})
    .Concat(list2.Select(x=>new {x.Barcode,x.reducedPrice,x.ItemPrice}))
    .GroupBy(
        x=>x.Barcode,
        (k,v)=>new {
            Barcode=k,
            DistinctReducedPrice=v.Select(x=>x.reducedPrice).Distinct().Count(),
            DistinctItemPrice=v.Select(x=>x.ItemPrice).Distinct().Count()
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Edit: For your new requirements (only intersection) you can modify the code above a little:

```
var commonKey = list1.Select(x=>x.Barcode).Intersect(list2.Select(x=>x.Barcode)).ToHashSet();

var result = list2.Where(x=>commonKey.Contains(x.Barcode)).Select(x=>new {x.Barcode,x.reducedPrice,x.ItemPrice})
    .Concat(list1.Where(x=>commonKey.Contains(x.Barcode)).Select(x=>new {x.Barcode,x.reducedPrice,x.ItemPrice}))
    .GroupBy(
        x=>x.Barcode,
        (k,v)=>new {
            Barcode=k,
            DistinctReducedPrice=v.Select(x=>x.reducedPrice).Distinct().Count(),
            DistinctItemPrice=v.Select(x=>x.ItemPrice).Distinct().Count()
        }
    )
    .ToList();

/*Result:
Barcode DistinctReducedPrice DistinctItemPrice
000     2                    2 
001     2                    2 
002     1                    1 
*/
```

This still doesn't explain, If you want the intersection, why the result has "099", since list2 doesn't contain it. Also, why do you expect 3 and 3 for "001" since it only has 2 different values (200 and 400; 360 and 860)?

Comment: Sir. Thank you. I edited the question. I don't want intersect result. Not a union result. I don't want data from list 2 if thay are not contain in list 1. Can you try again please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
var sameJanWithDiffPriceList3 = (from item in list1
      join t in list2 on item.Barcode equals t.Barcode into joined
      from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
      select new
      {
          Barcode = item.Barcode,
          reducedPrice = item.reducedPrice + "," + j.reducedPrice,
          ItemPrice = item.ItemPrice + "," + j.ItemPrice,
      }
      into grp
      group grp by new { grp.Barcode }
      into result
      select new
      {
         Barcode = result.Key,
         DistinctReducedPrice = string.Join(",", result.Select(a => a.reducedPrice).ToArray()).ToString().Replace(",0","").Split(',').Distinct().Count(),
         DistinctItemPrice = string.Join(",", result.Select(a => a.ItemPrice).ToArray()).ToString().Replace(",0", "").Split(',').Distinct().Count()
      }).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think you even need a join here. An union is way enough in his case.

Comment: I did not test the union, but I think it will. This was also a method.

Comment: @meysamasadi I get Nullreference Exception when data from list1 not contain data from list2. And I edited some parts of my question. Can you help again please.

Comment: I tested the code with new data. Works fine. what is the problem?!